Length of a roof cap to allow sun in during winter but cast a shadow during summer?
I'm designing a building on this height $(65.138140, 29.376434)$. What is notable this high up in the North is that sun shines nearly the whole day during the summer but barely raises above the horizon during the winter. The building would have large windows to the south. The cold climate requires buildings to be heated roughly from September to May.
I would like to use the sun as an auxillary heating element so that it would shine into the building between September and May but as the sun raises higher during the summer, it would remain above the cap of the roof from May to September allowing the building to remain cool.
The building would be $3.0$ meters in width. The roof of the building would be in $50°$ angle (allowing rain and snow to fall of off it easily). The base of the building would be $$2.4m\ \text{high (base height) + the height of the roof}$$
   sun                        _
  summer *      /\             | 
               /  \            |2.4m+roof height 
 sun       50°/|  |\ <- ?cap?  | 
winter *   2.4m|__|            | 
               3.0m           -
 
             |______|
              3.0m +
           roofcap width

What are the dimentions of the roof and especially what is the right length of the roof cap to cast a shade on to the building during May-September but to allow the sun directly to shine through the large windows heating it up during the September-May winter?

During September, according to https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/sun-angle , maximum angle of elevation is about $33°$. We can work using this data
